# How to define adjacency multi-list in java?

Tags: java, adjacency-list

I am trying to define adjacency multi-list in java. These type of lists are usually Edge based but I want to make it to be node/vertex based. Like list shows each vertex and edges associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to watch the Coursera courses regarding algorithms, they are really well done and cover also these topics.

Here you can follow the Graph.java class for undirected graph with adjacency list

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/Graph.java.html